# Trying to understand Object.assign behavior in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to understand this behavior I am observing with ES6 classes. Consider the following code. It's very simple: I have a parent class (`Parent`) and a child class (`Child`) inheriting from it. `Parent` class has a method called `getLabel` which simply returns the label property of that class.

When I create an instance of child class, set its label and try to print it all works well.

However when I create another instance of child class by using `Object.assign` on the 1st instance, the new instance preserves the label value of the 1st instance even though I am changing it explicitly.

```
class Parent {
  constructor(label) {
    this.getLabel = () => {
      return this.label;
    };
    this.label = label;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(label) {
    super(label);
    this.label = label;
  }
}

const c = new Child('Child');
console.log('c getLabel() = ' + c.getLabel());//Prints "Child"
const c1 = Object.assign(new Child('C1'), c);
c1.label = 'Child Modified';
console.log('c1 getLabel() = ' + c1.getLabel());//Prints "Child" again instead of "Child Modified".
```

I'm not sure why this is happening!

What I did then is changed the way I am defining `getLabel` method in `Parent` class:

```
class Parent2 {
  constructor(label) {
    this.label = label;
  }

  getLabel() {
    return this.label;
  }
}

class Child2 extends Parent2 {
  constructor(label) {
    super(label);
    this.label = label;
  }
}

const c2 = new Child2('Child 2');
console.log('c2 getLabel() = ' + c2.getLabel());//Prints "Child 2" as expected.
const c3 = Object.assign(new Child2('C3'), c2);
c3.label = 'Child 2 Modified';
console.log('c3 getLabel() = ' + c3.getLabel());//Prints "Child 2 Modified" as expected.
```

I would appreciate if someone can explain these two different behaviors.

Here's the ES6 Fiddle for the code above: http://www.es6fiddle.net/is6ex359/.

Comment: Arrow functions use lexical `this`. Your object has a property called `getLabel` that gets copied to your new child when you call `Object.assign`, that property contains a function that has a lexical `this` reference to the original Parent. If you used a normal function instead of an arrow function you would not see that behaviour.

Comment: By the way, `super(label)` already assigns `this.label`, so you don't need `this.label = label`.

Comment: @Oriol...Thanks! It was just me trying to come up with an example for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the `getLabel` is defined in each instance, it's not shared in the prototype. And since you define it using arrow functions, it does not define a local binding for `this`, the `this` value will be the one of the `constructor`.

Then, when you use `Object.assign`, `c1` receives the method of `c`, and the `this` value will be `c`, even if you call it on `c1`. So you get `c.label`, which is still `'Child'`.

So you should avoid arrow functions. I recommend defining the method in the prototype:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(label) {
    this.label = label;
  }
  getLabel() {
    return this.label;
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(label) {
    super(label);
    this.label = label;
  }
}
const c = new Child('Child');
console.log('c getLabel() = ' + c.getLabel()); // "Child"
const c1 = Object.assign(new Child('C1'), c);
c1.label = 'Child Modified';
console.log('c1 getLabel() = ' + c1.getLabel()); // "Child Modified"
```

(Note `Object.assign` does not assign `getLabel` because it's inherited, but `c1.getLabel ==== c.getLabel` anyways)

Or in the constructor, but using a function expression:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(label) {
    this.getLabel = function() {
      return this.label;
    };
    this.label = label;
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(label) {
    super(label);
    this.label = label;
  }
}
const c = new Child('Child');
console.log('c getLabel() = ' + c.getLabel()); // "Child"
const c1 = Object.assign(new Child('C1'), c);
c1.label = 'Child Modified';
console.log('c1 getLabel() = ' + c1.getLabel()); // "Child Modified"
```

Comment: This is the second question I've seen today where the problem was due to use of an arrow function. I guess people are falling in love with its simpler syntax, and not realizing that it has this significant difference in behavior.

Comment: It's great for callback functions, but not for object methods.

Comment: @Barmar: That's why I created http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196, but it's still specific (e.g. it doesn't fit this use case personally). Personally I would love to be able to close every question that misuses arrow functions as a duplicate of a single question, but that's probably just wishful thinking.